# postfix restrict delivery to only certain email addresses

Tags: postfix

Here is what I want to accomplish with postfix:  we do frequent copies of our production system that sends mail vendors, users, etc.  Occasionally after the copy, our technician forgets to turn off email sending so the test system starts sending out email to vendors etc causing confusion.  To prevent this I have asked our exchange team not to relay any mail from non production server.  However, we still need to be able to test from our development and QA systems so I setup postfix as a relay server for all the other system but I want to make sure postfix only delivers to a small list of developers and testers.  This way no rogue or unintended mail gets to an unintended recipient.  So in effect, reject ll mail except to people on a list.  I have tried various restrictions but have not seen any that achieve what I am trying to do.  I am hoping some one can help.  Thanks.

Comment: Using postfix's transport, relay domains, and relay recipients you can control which addresses it will relay to. Works great without anything special for a backup MX server, for your use case it seems somewhat duct-tape-ish.  @EsaJokinen 's answer is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do this with Postfix [transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) (using [`transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps)).

```
developer1@example.com   :
developer2@example.com   :
tester3@example.com      :
*                        error:You should not send mail from non-production servers.
```

Also, you could consider forwarding all mail from this test network into a shared mailbox for the developers and testers. This way your technicians won't have to remember changing the addresses at all, reducing their workload. I assume this Postfix server is just an SMTP gateway for your test network and has no other purposes. In this example, you can forget the `transport_maps` and use [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps), instead:

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

Then, add a wildcard regular expression for every address in `/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp`:

```
/.+@.+/ test-team.shared@example.com
```

Comment: The issue with forwarding to a shared mailbox is that when we do a production copy or QA refresh, there could be thousands of email queued that were ready to be sent out so I don't want those mail to go anywhere.  The shared mailbox could get flooded with all kinds of unintended mail.  I just want only the developers on the list to receive their mail.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I used the transport maps method and it works perfectly.  This is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking for a similar solution I found this:

https://postfwd.org/

If you do not trust this project, you can write your own replecement. It uses standard postfix interface http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html There is even an example perl filter in the documentation.

Postfix asks the filter about what to do with every email and the filter can decide. So you can implement any logic you want.